# Jquery loop over JSON each object returning error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Imt rying to loop over some JSON data that is returned and if the value returned is each to an html element attr add "checked" to the checkbox however this keep throwing an error.

```
$('.varUserSettingTable tr').each(function(index, el) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.each(curdata.VarUserDetails.VARS, function(index, value) {
        if (curdata.VarUserDetails.VARS[index] !== null) {
            if ($this.find('.SettingCheckbox').attr('name') === curdata.VarUserDetails.VARS[index].userID) {
                $this.find('.SettingCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Its throwing the error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userID' of undefined"**

on the if statmenet thats making sure .userID !== null

```
VarUserDetails: Object
VARS:Array[1024]
    [0 … 99]
        0:null
        1:null
        2:Object
            userChecked:1
            userID:"2"
            __proto__:Object
        3:Object
            userChecked:1
            userID:"3"
            __proto__:Object
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Why are you reading `curdata.VarUserDetails.VARS[index]` from within the iterator callback? You can simply use `value` instead.

Comment: I could be wrong but it looks like you have an array between `0:null` and `VARS`. So perhaps `value[index][index] !== null)` ?

Comment: Also, checking `value !== null` will not catch `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` itself is the item of the array. Trying use `value` instead of `curdata.VarUserDetails.Vars[index]`

```
$('.varUserSettingTable tr').each(function(index, el) {
var $this = $(this);
$.each(curdata.VarUserDetails.VARS, function(index, value) {
    if (value  !== null) {
        if ($this.find('.SettingCheckbox').attr('name') === value.userID) {
            $this.find('.SettingCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: perfect! and more efficient thank you, will award the question after the 5 minute timer